# Spark `distinct` ignoring `spark.default.parallelism` in local mode when using .config

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm creating a `SparkSession` like this:

```
SparkSession
      .builder().appName("foo").master("local")
      .config("spark.default.parallelism", 2).getOrCreate()
```

when I run (from a unit test, specs2)

```
((1 to 10) ++ (1 to 10)).toDS().distinct().count()
```

I get 200 partitions

```
19/12/02 10:29:34 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 200 tasks
...
19/12/02 10:29:34 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) in 46 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/200)
```

It is the `distinct` that is broken since `ds.rdd.getNumPartitions` gives `2`, while `ds.distinct().rdd.getNumPartitions` gives `200`.  `ds.rdd.groupBy(identity).map(_._2.head)` and `ds.rdd.distinct()` seems to work as expected.

Is this a bug in Spark or am I missing something???

Spark version: 2.4.0, 2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

After reading my own question I see that yes, this has to be a bug.

Create https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-30101

Can use `ds.rdd.distinct().toDS()` workaround for now.